# React redirection rendering a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have a React application running in production. When i am on, lets say /contacts page, an API call is made and if it returns a 404, i redirect the user to an error page ( /error ).

The redirection is happening to /error. I can see it in the url. But the issue is that the page rendered is a blank page. I don't know why. Please note I see one error in such scenario 'ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 16 failed'

Below is the main pieces of code I have.

```
// In the index.js
import React, { useEffect, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const Contact = React.lazy(() => import("./pages/Contact"));
const Error = React.lazy(() => import("./pages/Error"));

function App() {
const history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL
});

return (
<Router basename={"LB"} history={history}>
  <div>
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/error" component={Error} />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
);
} 

export default App;


// Inside the Contact page
axios.get(url)
.then((response)=>{console.log('success')})
.catch((error)=>{props.history.push("/error");})
```

Any suggestions or reason why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show more of the code around Route in index.js

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and debugging details, and what your expected result should be.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - I have edited the Question with all code details of Index.js. Please see and let me know if you require any more information.